# ASP.net extended with client side operations

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, asp.net, client-side

What is the best way to "extend" my ASP skill set to include more client side orientated actions. I am developing the growing need to do things "faster" , without post backs... I am talking about UI stuff, like resizing a div, changing some css, repositioning div's etc. Basic animation type stuff. No real "business logic". I don;t mind posting back for my crucial hardcore procedures.. I don;t wish to replace them with client side code. As stated, I am looking to improve the UI experience for my website visitors.

What is the natural progression here? I regularly add in jquery, and jscript stuff... but those are normally scripts pre-developed by whomever. I need to start implementing my own client side code.

For a vb.net developer, which route?

Jscript?
Java?
jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to ask the question over here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to double post, can an admin "move" it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of the many JavaScript frameworks would be of use in this effort.  I am partial to jQuery myself, but there are many options out there, like Dojo or ExtJS.  Check out [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) for a decent starting list w/ comparison.